# I can't add winhq Repository in Linux mint

Tags: repository, wine, ppa

when I try to run this command to add wine repository

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 1928, in <module>
    add_repository_via_cli(ppa_line, codename, "-y" in args, use_ppas)
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 187, in add_repository_via_cli
    if repo_exists(line):
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 232, in repo_exists
    repositories = SourcesList().list
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 273, in __init__
    self.matcher = SourceEntryMatcher(matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 470, in __init__
    dist = DistInfo(base_dir=matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distinfo.py", line 184, in __init__
    with open(dist_fname) as dist_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/python-apt/templates//Linuxmint.info'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 153, in apport_excepthook
    with os.fdopen(os.open(pr_filename,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/crash/_usr_lib_linuxmint_mintSources_mintSources.py.0.crash'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 1928, in <module>
    add_repository_via_cli(ppa_line, codename, "-y" in args, use_ppas)
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 187, in add_repository_via_cli
    if repo_exists(line):
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 232, in repo_exists
    repositories = SourcesList().list
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 273, in __init__
    self.matcher = SourceEntryMatcher(matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 470, in __init__
    dist = DistInfo(base_dir=matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distinfo.py", line 184, in __init__
    with open(dist_fname) as dist_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/python-apt/templates//Linuxmint.info'
```

I also tried to change focal to bionic and groovy but it doesn't work 
I think that this is a problem in the Repository itself but does anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The log file says: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/python-apt/templates//Linuxmint.info'`.

But your other post says that your are on Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS, and that you tried to install Python3: [Bug after a crash ACPI BIOS Error (BUG) : Can not resolve symbol AE_NOT_FOUND](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631450/bug-after-a-crash-acpi-bios-error-bug-can-not-resolve-symbol-ae-not-found)

So that means the following:

- There's no error with the repository, but from the Python3 you've installed.
- This is because of the Python you installed, this killed `python-apt` and also `apt`.

The error is pretty clear, you have killed your Linux installation. It's better to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS again and stop jumping Linux distributions because "it didn't worked" because you killed them. You've jumped from Ubuntu, to Linux Mint and then Pop!_OS in

If you choose the Ubuntu path, may I suggest you Xubuntu 20.04.02 LTS (http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/20.04/release/xubuntu-20.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso) instead, since you seem to want to customize your OS and that the default Pop!_OS and Ubuntu Desktop Environment (which is called Gnome 3) is very limited in that matter.

Comment: no you got that wrong when I got this error when I was on Linux mint and my hop was like this: Ubuntu >> Pop OS >> Linux Mint(Current and I don't think I am going to do a hop now)